# Set visible directories for SFTP access?

Tags: permissions, users, remote, ftp, sftp

I am setting up SFTP access to one of my machines running Linux with the Dropbear SSH server. When I SFTP onto the machine remotely, I can see the entire filesystem on it, even if I might not have write access.
How to I control what directories a user can see when connecting to my machine via SFTP? For example, what if I only want to make one directory, e.g. /ftp/, visible and accessible?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you'll need to run your dropbear ssh server inside a chroot'd jail if you want to restrict it to certain directories.

If you were using a recent OpenSSH, I'd suggest using the ChrootDirectory setting in your sshd_config.  It doesn't appear as though dropbear has a similar parameter, so you'll have to do it manually.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I don't know how to set up a chroot jail in Dropbear nor OpenSSH. Is there a link to more info? Or should I ask a new question? Thanks again.

Comment: here's a tutorial that covers much of what you'll need to do: http://www.howtoforge.com/chrooted-drop-bear-howto